# How to know which website has installed our wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

We are creating a Wordpress plugin and we want to know the urls of the wordpress websites on which our plugin is installed.

What code should we add to the plugin to receive the url of the wordpress website?

We need this information to see what type of websites are installing our plugin.

Note: We will notify users before downloading the plugin and at the time of activation that we will be receiving there website's url.

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69398/104023) could help.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, You can create a `get_urls.php` in `http://example.com/get_urls.php` for receiving and storing URLs.

get_urls.php

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
    file_put_contents('urls.log', date('[r] ') . $_GET['url'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
}
```

And add below code to your plugin.

```
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'send_url_in_activate', 10, 1 );

function send_url_in_activate( $plugin ) {
    if( $plugin !== "PLUGIN_DIR" ) { // e.g: woocommerce/woocommerce.php
        return;
    }

    $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://example.com/get_urls.php?url=' . get_site_url() );
}
```

Don't forget set your plugin dir.

Comment: Could you explain why we need to check for plugin directory url at all?

Comment: `activated_plugin` action execute on every plugin activation. check plugin directory to send the URL when your plugin has been activated.